# iOS OpenGL ES 1.1 jerky animation using CADisplayLink (reboot fixes for a while)

Tags: ios, opengl-es-1.1, cadisplaylink

I'm using OpenGL ES 1.1 and CADisplayLink to animate a 3d scene. If the iOS device has been rebooted fairly recently, the animation is smooth and the time delta between two displayLink.timestamp calls is fairly even. But after a few hours or days of the iOS device being used and my app is sometimes run a few times, the animation becomes jerky and the time deltas ramp up and then reset to a lower value only to ramp up again.

Like this:

> > 2012-09-01 23:42:58.770 [2678:707] dt= 0.021139
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:58.787 [2678:707] dt= 0.022183
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:58.804 [2678:707] dt= 0.023223
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:58.820 [2678:707] dt= 0.024270
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:58.837 [2678:707] dt= 0.009679
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:58.853 [2678:707] dt= 0.010750
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:58.870 [2678:707] dt= 0.011766
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:58.887 [2678:707] dt= 0.012806
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:58.903 [2678:707] dt= 0.013847
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:58.920 [2678:707] dt= 0.014890
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:58.937 [2678:707] dt= 0.015933
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:58.953 [2678:707] dt= 0.016976
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:58.970 [2678:707] dt= 0.018011
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:58.987 [2678:707] dt= 0.019055
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:59.003 [2678:707] dt= 0.020097
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:59.020 [2678:707] dt= 0.021143
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:59.037 [2678:707] dt= 0.022181
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:59.054 [2678:707] dt= 0.023222
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:59.071 [2678:707] dt= 0.024288
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:59.087 [2678:707] dt= 0.009624
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:59.103 [2678:707] dt= 0.010728
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:59.121 [2678:707] dt= 0.011763
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:59.137 [2678:707] dt= 0.012808
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:59.153 [2678:707] dt= 0.013847
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:59.170 [2678:707] dt= 0.014891
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:59.187 [2678:707] dt= 0.016002
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:59.203 [2678:707] dt= 0.016979
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:59.220 [2678:707] dt= 0.018016
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:59.237 [2678:707] dt= 0.019042
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:59.253 [2678:707] dt= 0.020099
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:59.270 [2678:707] dt= 0.021138
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:59.287 [2678:707] dt= 0.022185
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:59.304 [2678:707] dt= 0.023222
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:59.320 [2678:707] dt= 0.024265
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:59.337 [2678:707] dt= 0.009681
> >
> > 2012-09-01 23:42:59.354 [2678:707] dt= 0.010736

And then if the iOS device is rebooted the animation is smooth again.

The problem even occurs on my menu screen when almost no game related calculations are going on in the UpdateAnimation() function.

I don't understand what is going on and why a fresh reboot will always fix this problem for a while.

Comment: If you run Time Profiler against your application using an inverted call tree, do you see any obvious hotspots?

Comment: @Brad-Larson, I ran Time Profiler with an Inverted Call Tree and I don't see anything that looks like a hotspot to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem! I am using timestamp from CADisplayLink to calculate time between frames.  timestamp is a double, but I (incorrectly) assigned it to a float. This caused a loss of precision, and caused incorrect frame time calculation. timestamp grows from when the user has rebooted the device and eventually gets so big it needs to be a double to be used to accurately calculate the time between frames.